# field type as text and completion in elastic serach

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I am trying to have **title field** as both **text** and **completion** types in elastic search.

As shown below

```
PUT playlist
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 2,
    "number_of_replicas": 2,
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "custom_english_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "name": "english"
        },
        "english_stop": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_english_"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "custom_lowercase_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "english_stop",
            "custom_english_stemmer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "long",
        "index": false,
        "doc_values": false
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "custom_lowercase_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "completion"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The below **suggestion** query works

```
POST media/_search
{
  "_source": ["id", "title"], 
  "suggest": {
    "job-suggest": {
      "prefix": "sri",
      "completion": {
        "field": "title"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But **normal search** would fail on the same title

```
GET media/_search
{
    "_source": ["id", "title"], 
    "query" : {
        "query_string": {
           "query" : "*sri*",
            "fields" : [
              "title"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me solve this problem

Comment: Can you show a sample document and what both queries return ?

Comment: U should use n grams for completion, they are much better in terms of performance

Comment: any docs link for it ?

Comment: @Sharath, I tried your queries with your index setting and mapping and it returned the correct result to me, it would be better if you provide sample documents and expected documents for us to understand better your requirements.